# Conditions for a piecewise function to be continuous at 0.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_a:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as

$$f_a(x)=x^a\text{ if }x>0\text{  and }f_a(x)=0\text{ if } x\leq 0.$$

Now, I want to know the conditions on $a$ so that $f_a(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Intuitively, $a>0$ should be satisfied and this can be verified from a graphing software. However, I'm able to "show" that $f_a(x)$ is continuous for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ via the following faulty proof. But I can't tell where exactly I'm making a mistake.

So, my request is, could anyone help me spot it? It would be great if an alternative approach can be mentioned (without using RHS or LHS limits).

*Proof.* Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta<\epsilon^{1/a}$ and let $|x|<\delta$. Then,

[image]

Comment: If $a<0$, the function $x \mapsto x^a$ is not increasing, therefore the step $|x|^a < \delta^a$ is wrong.

Comment: If $a=0$, you can't even define $\epsilon^{1/a}$. This case needs to be handled separately.

Comment: You might want to try $a=-1$ and $\varepsilon=\frac1{10}$ and $x=\frac1{100}$ to see which step fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is defined as follows:
$$
f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
x^a\text{ if }x>0 \\
0 \ \ \text{ if } x\leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
Definitely, $$\lim_{x\to0^-}f_a(x) = 0$$
So, if $f_a$ is continuous at $0$, the right limit must equal to $0$, as well.
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f_a(x) = \lim_{x\to0^+}x^a:=L^+ \in (-\infty, +\infty)$$

1. If $a>0$,  then $L^+ = 0$  as desired.
2. If $a=0$, then $f_a \equiv 1$. Hence, $L^+ = 1 \neq 0$.
3. If $a<0$, then $L^+ = +\infty \neq 0$.